# Dynamic Collectives

Tags: frame, pallet-collective

In substrate all the existing frames assume a "static" set of Collectives, defined at runtime and with direct management of members using membership frame.

Does anyone have or know of a good example of dynamic collective creation.  Similar to CosmosSDKs group module?

Other than implementing everything from the ground up, any way to use collective and membership frame that exist but in a "create collective" kind of way.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/0226b55f9ffff28821458a71c84eb5d3e75f1794/substrate/frame/collective/src/lib.rs#L1059

`ChangeMembers` trait is implemented for collective pallet. So you can write anything to interacte with this trait(interface).

For example, you can write something like this in a pallet:

```rs
// pallet-example/lib.rs
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
    type ChangeMembers: ChangeMembers;
}

#[pallet::hooks]
impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {
    fn on_initialize(_: BlockNumberFor<T>) -> Weight {
        T::ChangeMembers::change_members_sorted(..);
    }
}

// runtime/lib.rs
impl pallet_example::Config for Runtime {
    type ChangeMembers = Council;
}

frame_support::construct_runtime! {
    Council,
    PalletExample,
    ..
}
```

Then you have a pallet that it can change the council members in every block.

Comment: Not what I am asking, but yes, dynamic member management of a static collective is there.  What I am asking is dynamic management of the collectives themselves.  Instead of a few defined at runtime, creating hundreds of collectives each with their own management of members.

Unless I am misunderstanding your response, please clarify if so?

Comment: This shows you how to change the members from outside. You can define your `dynamic` logic in the `pallet-example`.